# Non-blocking input in Gforth

Tags: time, keyboard-events, forth, gforth

If we take a very simple counter using ncurses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void) {
  struct timespec start;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
  {
    int key = -1;
    struct timespec delay, now;
    do {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &delay);
      delay.tv_sec = 0;
      delay.tv_nsec = 1000L * 1000L * 1000L - delay.tv_nsec;
      nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
      mvprintw(1, 1, "%ld\n", (long)(now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec));
      refresh();
      key = getch();
      if (key >= 0)
        break;
    } while (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec < 60);
  }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

it aborts after pressing any key (OK, because of `cbreak()` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> would always work without any extra effort...).

But we can make this more complicated, like adding a function to pause the counter or resetting it on the fly (+/- 1 second).

We definitely need a non-blocking keyboard input for this.

I wonder if it possible to do this in Gforth? OK, I know how to catch interrupts like SIGINT there, but something like above, working for *any* key or a *any* predetermined key?

Comment: I'm removing the C tag as this question IMO has little to do with C (i.e. won't benefit from the attention of C programmers). Feel free to add it back if you disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `key?`, it [returns a flag](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Single_002dkey-input.html) which is true if new input is available.

You can augment the following code as you see fit, but I think it explains the basic idea of running in a loop until a key is pressed.

```
: run-until-key ( -- )
    0
    begin
        \ place your terminal code here
        ." Num:" dup . cr
        1+
    key? until drop ;
```

If you want to wait for a specific key, just add an if before the until:

```
...
key? if key 13 = else false then until
...
```

You can also add your timer there.